# Finding baselines associated with a CR in the Telelogic Synergy command line

Tags: version-control, command-line-interface, cm-synergy

How would one find baselines associated with a CR in Telelogic Synergy using the CLI interface? I have tried `ccm query "cvtype='baseline' and cr('xxx')"`, but this doesn't produce any results.

From the GUI you can look at the properties of a baseline and see which CRs are associated with the baseline, but I can't seem to find the proper CLI magic to allow me to write a script to take a CR and list the baselines.

Answer (score 0):

I think associations between a baseline and a CR are handled with relationships (ccm relate). 
Search for "Predefined relationships" in the Synergy manual for a list of the existing relationship. When you know the name of the relationship you should then be able to use a query with the function has_relationship_name().

Answer (score 0):

Change request is associated more with a RELEASE rather than a BASELINE. So the following query will help you get the RELEASE, you can further run another query to retrieve the baseline.

To retrieve the release for the

```
ccm.exe query -f "%release %modify_time %create_time" "cr('xxxxx')"
```

Once you retrieve the RELEASE and MODIFY_TIME, run a new query to get the BASELINES

```
ccm.exe query -f "%objectname %modify_time %create_time" "(cvtype='project') and (release='pppp/qqqq') and (modify_time>=time('1/30/13'))" -s integrate
```

This way you will get a narrower list of BASELINES you can work with, I know this may not be the answer you are looking for but it might help.